# SSRS - Tablix inside tablix - not able to freeze the header row

Tags: reporting-services

I’m facing a problem where in my report has a Tablix inside another one.
I want the green band(that displays me the years) should freezes at the top when I scroll down vertically.

I want to attach the report itself but don't know how to go about it.

[image]

Comment: Check this link if it is helpful to you......  http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/10/ssrs-repeat-header-using-tablixtable.html  http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/10/ssrs-repeat-tablix-header-on-page-scroll.html

Comment: Hey Manoj, the problem I a facing is when we have tablix inside tablix and Im trying to fix the inner tablix;s header.
BTW, do you really feel that solution on first link is really working even for single tablix?? I have tried that but nothing happens.